# What could be a good design pattern to hold a pool of not interchageable objects?

Tags: design-patterns, singleton, pool

I'm looking for a good design pattern for this scenario:

I have a bunch of hardware devices, each one represented by a class in a C++ library (let's call that class *Device*). The computer using that library opens a **UDP socket** with each device (they're identified by a IP in my network). The communication bewteen library and devices is via **JSON messages**. So, the library sends and receives JSON objects via sockets.

First thing the library does is to discover the number of devices, asking for a JSON object that contains that information (the IP of each device, basically). After that, builds a vector with all the *Device* objects.

This could be seen as a **pool of objects**, because, at the end, I have a set of *Device* objects, each one encapsulating a network connection. But **they're not interchangeable**. In a pool of database connections, I can pick one object and use it to connect with my database. But if I need to send a message to a specific device, **I need that *Device* object. Not another one**.

The original creator of the class modeled it just as a **Singleton** containing a vector. Because we just want one entry point to access the vector of *Device* objects. But I think this [can cause problems](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/singleton.html#why-we-regret-using-it).

**Are there better ways to model this class?**

Comment: One clarification: each device has its own socket, right? I.e. you are not broadcasting?

Comment: I am confused: Are you trying to make sure you don't mix up various devices when send a message? Like: Group A: devices:{1,2,3,4,5} Group B: devices:{7,8,9,} and you don't accidentally want to communicate with device 1 and device 9 (since they are from different groups?) or, you want to essentially ease management of these devices by referring to them non-uniquely?

Comment: @Groo: Yes, each device has its own socket. Christian: I just want to keep each Device as separated entity. Sometimes, I group several devices to send a message to all of them, but this is just a use case. I need to manage them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call this collection a [pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pool_%28computer_science%29). The point of having a pool of objects is to reduce instantiation costs of multiple instances of the same type, allowing the client to "return" the resource back to the pool after using it. Your devices cannot be interchanged transparently, and the point of the collection is not related to resource usage at all.

There are two approaches that come to my mind:

1. You can use a `map` to quickly fetch a certain `Device` using its unique key (e.g. `std::map<std::string, Device>`, but you should probably have a better idea of what to use as the key instead of a plain string), similar to:

   ```
   // find the right device instance
   string deviceInfo = "some-unique-key";
   Device device = devicesMap.find(deviceInfo)->second;

   // send the data
   string json = serialize(dataObject);
   device.send(json);
   ```

   On the other hand, you might want to delegate the actual (de)serialization to the `Device` itself, in case that the protocol might differ for some devices:

   ```
   // find the right device instance
   string deviceInfo = "some-unique-key";
   Device device = devicesMap.find(deviceInfo)->second;

   // send the object, Device class will know how to serialize it
   device.send(dataObject);
   ```
2. Another interesting alternative is to send the messages to all `Device` instances, and let them decide if the message is relevant for them (based on whatever you think it's appropriate). This approach allows scenarios where multiple devices can dispatch the same message, if they feel like it, or simply be notified that something happened without even sending anything:

   ```
   // notify all devices that we have a message
   for (auto &device : devicesVector) {

       // you are only notifying the device.
       // each instance should decide whether or not to
       // pass the message forward (based on its contents),
       // and how to serialize it

       device.notify(dataObject);
   }
   ```

The fact that your current implementation is a Singleton is a separate issue. Singleton is a creational pattern, related to the object's lifetime, and is usually used only to avoid passing the dependency around. It simplifies ctor signatures a bit, but there might be some laziness involved also, especially considering the fact that you make unit-testing a bit harder.

Proper [dependency injection patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) would require you to pass this service explicitly to all consumers (usually thorough constructor injection), which would result in less coupling and in turn allow easier unit testing. This doesn't mean you need to refactor your entire code to use a DI container, but simply pass the "thingy" which handles communication to its callers through their constructors.

Comment: Many thanks! I definitely go for dependency injection, apart from Factory pattern. Really useful feedback!

Comment: Note that the 'factory' part mentioned in Christian's answer is the part that I wanted to avoid, because of its testability issues. If you do unit testing, you will soon find out that a static factory method is (in terms of testing) very similar to a Singleton. Unless you have a way to inject a "mock manager" in place of the `DeviceManager` returned by `getInstance()`, you won't have a way to create mocked `Device` instances for your test methods. That's why it's usually better to inject the "manager" instance through the constructor, instead of accessing it through a public static method.

Comment: Actually, after working a bit more in the library, I think that DI is the best solution. And to ensure the single instance of my manager class (it's a class holding a vector of unique objects), I think this will work fine http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/singleton.html#to-limit-a-class-to-a-single-instance

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be that what you need is an [Abstract Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)

The idea is that you ask a factory for an object that ties together all related components so that you can't get them wrong. This is classically used in UI design (to make sure, for example, that you can't accidentally mix Windows buttons with Mac Style combo boxes) but directly applies to you.

So, in Java syntax (since I haven't written C++ in years)

```
// this is where you do the discovery you mentioned.
DeviceManager manager = DeviceManager.getInstance(); 

Device d = manager.getDevice("some-id");
// device c, d will be from the same set here because a reference to them 
// can only come through this manager
Device c = manager.getDevice("c-id");
```

The [Composite Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_Pattern) is also very handy for hiding cascading messaging functionality if that's what you need.